# Calling a class method from a custom method

Tags: delphi, methods

I'm relatively new to Delphi, so please pardon my ignorance.

As an exercise, I am writing a little MasterMind game. The idea is that, when the user derives the correct number, a custom method (`Congrats`) executes.

One of the options in this method is to play again. The obvious step following this is that the form must be reset to its default ("start up") state. I have created a type method for that (`Resetform`, declared as a method in `public`, as it needs to access the controls). I can't call that from `Congrats`, but I noticed that I can call it from other event handlers.

Is it possible to do this, and if so, how do I go about it?

Works from event handler, but not from custom procedure.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual code you are having trouble with

Answer (score 1):

The method `Resetform` is a method of your form, which is why you can call it from event handler of your form, they reside in the same object.

To call your `Resetform` from outside the context of your form, you need a reference to your form, otherwise the code won't know which instance of your form it needs to call `Resetform` on.

Now, assuming you call `Congrats` from your form, you could add a parameter and call it like this:

```
Congrats(Self)
```

And your procedure could be implemented as

```
procedure Congrats(AForm : TMyForm); // "TMyForm" being the class of your form
begin
  ...
  AForm.Resetform;
end;
```

But then, you could as well make `Congrats` a method of your form instead.

If `Congrats` is not called from your form, then you will need to find another way to pass your form's reference to the function, or use another approach.